# How can test eax, eax generate a signal 11?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64

`Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.`

```
(gdb) info registers 
rax            0x0      0
rip            0x496272 0x496272 <my_function+464>
eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
```

The code in question looks like this.

```
if ( ... a->b->c.d & 0x100 ... )
```

The disassembly is

```
   0x0000000000496262 <+448>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x30]
   0x0000000000496266 <+452>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax+0x10]
   0x000000000049626a <+456>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax+0x48]
   0x000000000049626d <+459>:   and    eax,0x100
=> 0x0000000000496272 <+464>:   test   eax,eax
   0x0000000000496274 <+466>:   je     0x49628b <my_function+489>
...
   0x0000000000496286 <+484>:   jmp    0x49636f <my_function+717>
   0x000000000049628b <+489>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x30]
   0x000000000049628f <+493>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax+0x10]
```

There doesn't appear to be any memory access problems since GDB can print the accessed field, and the code didn't fault on the `mov` operation.

```
(gdb) p a->b->c.d
$1 = 0
```

There are no other threads running at the same time.

My guess currently is that the problem is somewhere else and GDB or the core file has incomplete or incorrect information.

- The build machine is SLES9
- The compiler is GCC 3.4.4
- The execution host is RHEL6.4
- GDB is 7.2-60.el6

Comment: What is instruction after `test eax,eax`?

Comment: Its a jump.  I updated the description.

Comment: Does issuing a backtrace point to the same place too ? (In this case, %rip is likely wrong, and the crash is elsewhere

Comment: Is it a multithreaded program? Is the fault reproducible? What happens if you put a breakpoint on the previous instruction then do `si`?

Comment: @Jester It's not multithreaded, it's stated on the question.

Comment: @nos. GDB can produce a good backtrace from the core file.  Looks like the stack is OK.

Comment: @Jester.  In regard to reproducibility.  Its not easy, QA didn't hit it until after several days.  I have coded a simple C program that reproduces similar code and data based on the info in the core file, but cannot reproduce it.  The thought occurred to me to run it in a VM that takes regular snapshots. When it happens, just restart from a previous snapshot, attach GDB, wait for it to happen.

Comment: Could also be hardware problem, unless you got it at least twice in the same spot.

Comment: Are you sure a compiler made this code, and that it hasn't been corrupted?  `and eax, 0x100` already sets flags based on the result, so `test eax,eax` is redundant.  (unless some other code branches to the `test` instruction, I guess, to test eax without masking it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, Check how GCC 4.4 produces assembly for this code `int a = 0; if (a & 0x100) a = 1;`

Comment: @MichaelClosson: Oh right, you're using a debug build; that makes sense, but wasn't obvious the way it usually is from the surrounding code.  That's not how gcc `-O3` compiles that test, [even in cases where `a` isn't a compile-time constant.](https://godbolt.org/g/OPa3FK).  But yeah, changing -O3 to -O0, I see the same and/test idiom.

Comment: Are you sure the signal was sent by the kernel, and not by another process with the `kill(2)` system call?  This theory is highly unlikely unless you have some weird processes on your system; sending `SIGSEGV` is a really weird choice for inter-process communication, vs. `SIGUSR1` or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Hmm. Interesting idea. There's no evidence of it, but since a SEGV caused by a test on registers is probably not possible, ...

Comment: Signals do come with information on their source, which a signal handler can decode.  e.g. `strace cat` and compare the results of `^c` vs. `killall cat`.  BTW, is it possible that the test&branch is branching to an unreadable address?  Probably not, because in that case the fault would happen with EIP = the bad address.  Unlike perf counters, exceptions are "precise", and are always reported on the correct instruction.  (I think even when compare-and-branch instructions macro-fused into a single uop).  Only other thing I can think of: something called `mprotect(2)` without `PROT_EXEC`.

Comment: @PeterCordes `mprotect` works with page granularity so that would have already caused a fault earlier (assuming the code flow was linear). But in general, yeah, for instructions that can't otherwise fault a non-executable page could be a reason.

Comment: @Jester: that's why I didn't mention `mprotect` sooner, since `test` wasn't the first insn in a page or following a `call`.  And probably not a branch target.  Since the OP said this is a single-threaded process, the only way I can imagine `mprotect` happening is from a signal handler.  But that can't explain consistently faulting at the same address, when the code faults at all.  I forget if that was established... Other times when you reproduce this, is the fault always at this instruction?

Comment: Now that's evil .. mprotect from a signal handler :)

Comment: @Jester: Yeah, really scraping the bottom of the barrel on plausible ideas.  If the fault address isn't the same every time, I'm leaning towards problems hardware.  Or maybe a driver bug.  (Non-driver kernel bugs are unlikely).  Incorrect TLB handling could produce faults like this in user-space processes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great ideas.  Peter, I get your asm examples. Using a global or function call argument avoids optimizing away the code, and indeed the optimized code doesn't have both `and` and `test`. A non executable page could cause this, which could happen if the instruction aligns to a page boundary, is the target of a jump, or if `mprotect` is called in a signal handler.  Unfortunately `$_siginfo` doesn't provide any additional information.  To my knowledge this is the first time this bug has been produced.  Lastly, I think I'll use this thread for a job interview question. ;)